# Calculating row number without ROW_NUMBER function. How does it work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just came across a way to get row numbers without `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
SELECT name, sal, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM EMPLOYEE i WHERE o.name >= i.name) row_num
FROM EMPLOYEE o
order by row_num
```

There is some explanation [HERE](http://dwbi.org/database/sql/72-top-20-sql-interview-questions-with-answers) 
But I am still not clear on this.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is calculating a function related to `rank()` rather than `row_number()`, unless you can guarantee that `name` is unique.

Answer (score 3):

This is example of [`correlated subquery`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT name, sal, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM EMPLOYEE i WHERE o.name >= i.name) row_num
FROM EMPLOYEE o
order by row_num
```

> Many queries can be evaluated by executing the subquery once and
>   substituting the resulting value or values into the WHERE clause of
>   the outer query. In queries that include a correlated subquery (also
>   known as a repeating subquery), the subquery depends on the outer
>   query for its values. This means that the **subquery is executed
>   repeatedly, once for each row that might be selected by the outer
>   query.**

Let's assume you have:

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ NAME  ║ SAL ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ Anno  ║  80 ║
║ Bhuti ║  60 ║
║ Darl  ║  80 ║
║ Hash  ║ 100 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

For `Anno` in outer query, subquery will return only

```
╔══════╦═════╗
║ NAME ║ SAL ║
╠══════╬═════╣
║ Anno ║  80 ║
╚══════╩═════╝
```

For `Bhuti` it will return:

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ NAME  ║ SAL ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ Anno  ║  80 ║
║ Bhuti ║  60 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

For `Darl` it will return:

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ NAME  ║ SAL ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ Anno  ║  80 ║
║ Bhuti ║  60 ║
║ Darl  ║  80 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

And so on. The `COUNT` function will get you number of rows. You should also spot that outer query and subquery use the same table `EMPLOYEE`. Aliases `o` and `i` are used to distinguish them.

You can think about **`correlated subqueries`** as a way of looping in set based environment.

**EDIT:**

This is poor equivalent of `ROW_NUMBER` function. [`Example from question`](http://dwbi.org/database/sql/72-top-20-sql-interview-questions-with-answers):

> Generating a row number – that is a running sequence of numbers for
>   each row is not easy using plain SQL. In fact, the method I am going
>   to show below is not very generic either. **This method only works if
>   there is at least one unique column in the table.** This method will
>   also work if there is no single unique column, but collection of
>   columns that is unique. Anyway, here is the query:

Comment: hmm..but this isn't a good practice if the NAME column isn't unique, am I right?

Comment: @kenlacoste Yes, it will work correct only for unique column/column combination